# ssh-agent not working in Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, ssh-agent

I freshly installed Kubuntu 19.04 but I used my old home folder from Linux Mint. `.bashrc` and `.profile` are Kubuntu versions.

When using ssh, I everytime need to type my pass phrase. I can manually `ssh-add` my key but after a boot, I still need to enter my passphrase again. That's annoying.

`ssh-agent` seems to be running at the time I try to connect.

What could cause this?

Comment: this is true for kubuntu 20.04 too

Answer (score 4):

KDE seems not to start `ssh-agent` automatically. To solve this, install `ksshaskpass` and

`nano ~/.config/autostart-scripts/ssh-add.sh`

Enter the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
export SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ksshaskpass
/usr/bin/ssh-add $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa </dev/null
```

Check if the path is correct with `whereis ksshaskpass`
If you have multiple keys just separate them with a space.

Make the script executable 
`chmod u+x ~/.config/autostart-scripts/ssh-add.sh`

Test it 
`sh ~/.config/autostart-scripts/ssh-add.sh`

After a log-off and in again you will be prompted for a passphrase and this time it will be stored.

Comment: How to add all keys automatically as we create one ? @Corni