# SSH Key Registration Not Preventing Prompting of Password

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, kde, password, ssh-agent

I recently switched from Ubuntu 19.10 to Kubuntu 19.10.

Ever since doing so, servers I ssh to always prompt me for password, even though I've used `ssh-copy-id` to register my public ssh key with those servers. I've tried redoing these key registrations, but I'm still getting prompted for password, each time I connect.

In Kubuntu, how can I get my ssh keys registered in a way where I don't have to type passwords for each ssh server I connect to?

**More Info:** In Ubuntu 19.10 my home folder was on a separate partition. So when I installed Kubuntu 19.10, I didn't repartition the home folder. However, I tried to delete every private folder I could, except for a handful like `.config/AppName` folders (and my .ssh folder of course) that I knew I wanted to keep configurations for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Ubuntu (running GNOME) uses `seahorse` and the GNOME keyring to auto import the SSH keys into your SSH Key Agent, it doesn't always do that when you're using Kubuntu or another desktop environment because of different management agents.

For each of the SSH private keys in your SSH folder you want to use, you need to run `ssh-add /home/$USER/.ssh/keyname` to add each SSH key into the SSH agent's keyring for automatic authenticating to work.

Comment: Although this worked initially, rebooting puts me right back into the same state as before (being prompted for a password each time I try to make a ssh connection). How can I persist what `ssh-add` is only accomplishing temporarily?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159868/256054) is the issue I'm having.

Comment: @LonnieBest yes it seems so.  you need to start ssh-agent and maybe that answer will fix it persistently